# How to get 'count of nodes' XML, with adobe air

Tags: xml, count, air

i want to ask how How to get count of nodes XML with sign 'question'...

If i have some xml data like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <questioner>
     <question>
         <id>001</id>
         <content>soal 1</content>
          <answer>a</answer>
     </question>
     <question>
          <id>002</id>
          <content>soal 2</content>
         <answer>a</answer>
     </question>
    <question>
          <id>003</id>
          <content>soal 3</content>
          <answer>a</answer>
    </question>
    <question>
          <id>004</id>
          <content>soal 4</content>
          <answer>a</answer>
    </question>
</questioners>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml:XML = ... //init xml
var questionList:XMLList = xml.elements("question");
questionList.length // question count
```

This is not specific to AIR, Flash has XML capabilities everywhere.

Comment: Hii.. alxx.. i mean in AIR please... could you? thanks before

Comment: I got it and the code like this : prefsXML = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
stream.close();
var domParser = new DOMParser();  var XMLList = prefsXML.getElementsByTagName("question"); alert(XMLList .length);

Comment: Well, you didn't mentioned that you need to load it. If your questions are all on top level, you don't need DOMParser - XML(string) will be enough.